# Passing compare function into qsort c++

Tags: c++, sorting

My compare function is dependent on data members in Foo and I therefore wish to contain it in this class. All examples use global functions which works but its not what I'm looking for. I'd like each instance of Foo to have a different compare based on the current status of the object.

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo(){}

   int Compare(const void * a,const void * b)
   {
    //Comparing logic
    //This is fine
   }

   void SortStuff(void)
   {
    qsort(ObjectArray,MAXOBJECTS,sizeof(Object*), Compare);
   }    

};
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). It makes this kind of thing trivial.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. `qsort` can't accept pointer to non-static member function.

Comment: ...and implement operator< for your comparison.

Comment: @jbruni No need for that, unless that operator makes sense for the type in question.

Comment: Try making the `Compare` function `static`.  The `qsort` function requires the comparison function to be free standing or accessible without referring to an object.

Answer (score 1):

As @juanchopanza mentioned in a comment, it is strongly recommended that you use `std::sort` over `qsort` in C++. The `std::sort` algorithm correctly calls assignment operators and is type-safe, while `qsort` does not. For example, if you try using `qsort` to sort an array of `std::string`s, you'll get undefined behavior.

That said, if you absolutely must use `qsort` this way, the problem you're running into is the "invisible `this`" pointer. In C++, member functions are fundamentally different than free functions because in order to call a member function, you need to provide a receiver object. In the code you've written above, you're getting an error because `qsort` expects a free function that can be called with two arguments, but you've given it a member function that wants two arguments, which effectively really needs three arguments - a receiver object and two pointers.

To fix this, you have a few options. One option would be to mark the function `static`, indicating that it is a free function scoped inside your class rather than a member function. Another option would be to use lambdas to define the comparison function, since C++ lambdas without capture lists are free functions. I'd actually recommend that second option over the first unless you need the comparison function in multiple places, since it more clearly indicates that you just need the function as a one-off.